# Add comma to text box after space bar is pressed

Tags: jquery

I have value(s) I retrieve via an Ajax request when a page loads. I present them in a text box for a user to adjust. Remove or add. I need to add a comma after the last char, but only after the space bar is pressed.

I have found some similar questions, but none address this specific issue. I've not found a duplicate question.

I've been tinkering with this small piece of code, but it limits me. I cannot backspace and delete, and it will not accept anything under two chars.

```
$('#symText').keyup(function(){
  var sym = this.value.replace(/(\w)[\s,]+(\w?)/g, '$1, $2');
  if (sym!=this.value) this.value = sym; 
});
```

Seeking an alternative that only adds a comma after the last char when the space bar is pressed. Your help is always greatly appreciated.

```
          $.ajax({
                url: '/Trucking/GetSubSymbols',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: sendData,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);

                    var s = '';
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        s += data[i] + ',';
                    }
                    $(".fillSym").val(s);

                },
                error: function () {
                    //alert('Error');
                    console.log('Error');
                }
            });
```

PIC of the tb
[image]

Comment: This sounds annoying for your users; if I accidentally hit space I expect to press delete once, but your JS code added an unwanted `,` in there, so now I have to do it twice unexpectedly. Similarly, what happens if someone just presses space multiple times and fills the box with `,` characters? It's not easy to validate the garbage which was entered. It may be better if you separate each value out in to its own box and then create an array from them.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I realize that's the first impression, it's actually making things easier for them. They would have to add a comma regardless. There are an unknown set of values coming in from the Ajax request. So, unless I can dynamically create that exact number of text boxes to display those values with the ability of adding additional tb's for more values, I have to use my current method. I'll have to learn. I don't know if that's possible. Each value is stored separate in the db, so if anything is added or removed I can check and add/remove as necessary.

Comment: `unless I can dynamically create that exact number of text boxes to display those values with the ability of adding additional tb's for more values` you can. It's quite straightforward and definitely the approach I would suggest

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan any advice that can point me in the right learning direction?

Comment: Are you sure the original values will never contain a comma or a space? Also, why do you want to have them separated with commas?

Comment: @David I added the ajax call and a pic of the tb to show more. I purposely add the comma there, so that when the user submits this page I'll store them in an array and loop back through them in the server to see if anything new is added or removed.

Comment: @swapmeet_Lou sure, here's a very rough example of how to create the inputs from the AJAX request data, add new inputs, and how to serialise the user input to send back to the server to update your datastore: https://jsfiddle.net/3au1x420/

Comment: It seems that your values don't contain spaces (that will break your method). So you can forget about the commas: don't add them inside the `$.ajax` function and send the edited string to the server also without commas. Then, in the server, convert the string to array using the space as separator.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Vati down below answered nearly verbatim what I was looking for in my question, but after looking at your response that made a lot of sense to me. I accepted his answer as it does legit answer what I originally wanted, but your answer has me rethinking this whole approach. Grateful for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it here let me know if its what you want )

```js
$('input[name="numbers"]').on('keyup',function(e){
  if(e.which === 32){
    var str = $(this).val().split('');
    if(str[str.length - 2] === ','){
      $(this).val($(this).val().replace(' ',''));
    }
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(' ',','));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="numbers" value="61,62,63"/>
```